# Sum and product of dependent probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with the field of probability distributions. However, I am trying to compute the probability density function of a random variable $Z=AX+\delta AX$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $\delta \sim p_\Delta$ and $x \sim p_X$.

I figured out that by the product rule of two random variables, say $Y:=\delta AX$ it holds
$$
p_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p_X(x) p_\Delta(\frac{y}{x}) \frac{1}{\vert x \vert}\ dx.
$$
Can we now apply the summation rule and write the sum in $Z$ as
$$p_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p_X(s) p_Y(z-s) \ ds = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p_X(s) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p_X(x) p_\Delta(\frac{z-s}{x})\frac{1}{\vert x \vert} \ dxds$$
to obtain the distribution of $Z$?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the summation rule only works for independant variables, but you can instead directly use the product rule on $Y = (1 + \delta)AX$, knowing that the distribution of $1 + \delta$ is $\tau_{-1}p_\Delta : x \mapsto p_\Delta(x - 1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer @Cactus ! If I understand correctly, for $Y = (1+\delta )AX$ we then have $p_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_X(x) p_\Delta(\frac{y}{x}-1) \frac{1}{\vert x \vert} \ dx$, right?

Comment: I am not completely sure on how the product rule works with vectors/matrices instead of real numbers so be careful about it. And you should start by computing the distribution of $AX$ in function of the distribution of $X$ (it shouldn't be too hard because $A$ is deterministic), I am pretty sure $A$ should appear in the final formula.